# Is it possible to centralize the Grunt modules?

Tags: node.js, optimization, gruntjs

I have recently started using grunt for well, running tasks. It seems faster at compiling and concatenating my JS and LESS. It also does a great job of watching for Photoshop Image assets and moves them/process them as needed.

I didn't give it much thought until I accidentally uploaded the node_modules folder and noticed that it was about 80mb.

Is this really the case? That if I were to have 10 projects based off the same grunt task that I will have almost 800 mb of space used up by 10 identical copies of the grunt-contrib?

I am not a Ruby guy but was under the impression that Gems were installed at a central point and available to other apps on the system.

Answer (score 1):

You ***can*** install Grunt plugins globally, just use the `-g` flag: `npm install -g grunt-contrib-uglify` ... However, the point of installing them in the project using the `package.json` file is that any other developer that wants to run/test/build the code need only run `npm install` in the project directory to install all dependencies. If you go the global route, then each developer will have to individually run `npm install -g plugin-name` for each one that is required - a very time-intensive (and annoying) process.

That said, if you are using source control (you are, right? ;)) then you **should not** commit your `node_modules` directory, only commit your `package.json` file. This is for many reasons, not the least of which is that those dependencies take up a lot of space (as you mention) and can be re-downloaded any time the project is pulled down on a new machine.

Comment: I got blasted on Twitter for asking this question, it is I guess so against Node law or something.

I am using SC but have a bunch of projects all with the same grunt file, and am filling my Tiny SSD for no reason.

I suppose I could delete and reinstall the packages when it becomes an issues.

The thing that gets me is that Grunt is a tool, where a Node package is app specific.

Why I would need 10 copies of the less compiler is beyond me. It is a Grunt problem not a Node problem.

Comment: These are good points, and I understand the concern. As for the 10 copies of less, that has more to do with different projects being able to work with different versions. There are cases for us where I need a specific version of a library in one project, but the latest version in another.

Comment: It would be nice if Grunt had some sort of versioned vendor folder. After all most people install less globally.